# Precedence of is/not/or/and in C#

Tags: c#

What is the order of precedence for pattern matching "is not"?  I realized I've written some code like this:

```
if (x is not TypeA or TypeB)
```

And implicitly assumed I was writing:

```
if (!(x is TypeA) && !(x is TypeB))
```

But I just realized that it might be evaluating as:

```
if ((!x is TypeA) || (x is TypeB))
```

In other words, does the "not" apply to an "or separated" list, or does it just apply to the next argument in the list.  Does my original statement need to be written as this instead:

```
if (x is not TypeA and not TypeB)
```

Comment: If only there was some way to test it.

Comment: Yep, I'll test it and post an answer if someone else doesn't.  But I can't find any documentation online on how precedence works with those operators, so I figured it was useful to post the question publicly in case other people have had the same thought pattern.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It does in C# 9.0 and above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3

Comment: oh, I thought I deleted the comment. Yeah, the type operators are special in C# (with the new pattern matching syntax and how it works), like the relational operators in Python. And it does appear that there isn't particularly good documentation available on this kind of nuance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a test program:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }

A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new B();
A a3 = new C();

Console.WriteLine("A is not B or C " + (a1 is not B or C));
Console.WriteLine("B is not B or C " + (a2 is not B or C));
Console.WriteLine("C is not B or C " + (a3 is not B or C));

Console.WriteLine("A is not (B or C) " + (a1 is not (B or C)));
Console.WriteLine("B is not (B or C) " + (a2 is not (B or C)));
Console.WriteLine("C is not (B or C) " + (a3 is not (B or C)));

Console.WriteLine("A is not B and not C " + (a1 is not B and not C));
Console.WriteLine("B is not B and not C " + (a2 is not B and not C));
Console.WriteLine("C is not B and not C " + (a3 is not B and not C));
```

And here's the output:

```
A is not B or C True
B is not B or C False
C is not B or C True

A is not (B or C) True
B is not (B or C) False
C is not (B or C) False

A is not B and not C True
B is not B and not C False
C is not B and not C False
```

So "is not (B or C)" is the same as "is not B and not C".

But "is not B or C" checks that it's not B or is C, which is probably never something you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Bryce Wagner explained it very well, I'll just expound on the issue with `if (x is not TypeA or TypeB)`.

```
    enum Foo{
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 3
    }

    var a = Foo.A;
    var b = Foo.B;
    var c = Foo.C;
    
    Console.WriteLine($"a is not Foo.B or Foo.C: {(a is not Foo.B or Foo.C)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"b is not Foo.B or Foo.C: {(b is not Foo.B or Foo.C)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"c is not Foo.B or Foo.C: {(c is not Foo.B or Foo.C)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"c is not Foo.C or Foo.C: {(c is not Foo.C or Foo.C)}\n");
    
    //The 4 lines above are equivalent to the 4 below:      
    Console.WriteLine($"a != Foo.B || a == Foo.C: {(a != Foo.B || a == Foo.C)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"b != Foo.B || b == Foo.C: {(b != Foo.B || b == Foo.C)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"c != Foo.B || c == Foo.C: {(c != Foo.B || c == Foo.C)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"c != Foo.C || c == Foo.C: {(c != Foo.C || c == Foo.C)}");
```

The result is:

```
1    a is not Foo.B or Foo.C: True
2    b is not Foo.B or Foo.C: False
3    c is not Foo.B or Foo.C: True
4    c is not Foo.C or Foo.C: True
5
6    a != Foo.B || a == Foo.C: True
7    b != Foo.B || b == Foo.C: False
8    c != Foo.B || c == Foo.C: True
9    c != Foo.C || c == Foo.C: True
```

For line 6 (and its equivalent on line 1) above:
if `a != Foo.B` is true, then there's no need to check if `a == Foo.C`. Checking if `a == Foo.C` at this point is like writing the following:

```
if (1 != 2 || 1 == 3) //(true or false) always returns true
```

For line 7 (and its equivalent on line 2) above:

```
if (2 != 2 || 2 == 3) //(false or false) always returns false
```

For line 8 (and its equivalent on line 3) above:

```
if (3 != 2 || 3 == 3) //(true or true) always returns true
```

For line 9 (and its equivalent on line 4) above - both conditions are for the same variable, but one will always be false, and the other will always be true, leading to a logical redundancy in the code:

```
if (c != 3 || c == 3) //obviously always returns true
```